# Configuring Visual Studio to Recognize Real Folders Instead of Filters for Including Headers and Source Files

Tags: visual-studio

I am encountering difficulties configuring Visual Studio to recognize real folders instead of filters for organizing my project files. Specifically, I want Visual Studio to recognize the "include" folder as the location for header files and the "src" folder as the location for source files.

Currently, even after removing all filters and reorganizing my files accordingly, Visual Studio continues to treat the files within these folders as miscellaneous items. As a result, I am experiencing limitations in terms of IntelliSense, code navigation, and successful builds with MSBuild.

In an attempt to resolve this issue, I have taken the following steps:

Removed all filters in my project.
Created a dedicated "include" folder for header files.
Created a separate "src" folder for source files.
However, despite these efforts, Visual Studio still fails to recognize the designated folders for headers and source files, leading to reduced productivity and difficulty in effectively navigating and building my project.

I have conducted thorough research on this topic but have been unable to find a clear solution that addresses my specific requirement. Therefore, I am seeking guidance on how to configure Visual Studio appropriately to recognize these folders as the designated locations for headers and source files.

Any recommendations, insights, or potential solutions to achieve this configuration in Visual Studio would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!